# Use VLOOKUP output as cell reference for other sheet

Tags: excel, reference, vlookup

I have come across a problem, I need to copy specific cells from one sheet to another based on a dropdown menu. So the selected cells do chance based on the word one selects in the dropdown. As I look up the cells to be copied with VLOOKUP in need the gotten result to reference in the other sheet like visible here:

We are in sheet Overview, I look up the value in Helper and want to write the value from FTEsSZ_2021

```
=FTEsSZ_2021!VLOOKUP(Overview!A3;Helper!A2:B21;2;FALSE)
```

As this statement doesn't work and I tried everything, has someone an idea how that works without VBA?

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Possibly using `INDIRECT` but your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: I think INDEX and MATCH would be ideally for your case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "write the value from FTEsSZ_2021"?

Comment: @BigBen INDIRECT did it with a little help around, thank you

Comment: @P.b so the VLOOKUP gave back a cell reference (for example C9) which is then used to read read the value in this cell (in this example C9) from the FTEsSZ_2021 sheet. Is this understandable? sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Yes, I see you already received a reply about using INDIRECT for using indirect references.